# agregar fila a tabla y borrar fila de tabla. y confirmar que funciona un contador de productos y un contador de total

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, eventos, tablas

No puedo hacer que al hacer click en la variable link, se creen los respectivos td y tr, con la informacion requerida (nombre y precio del producto). Y al lado de eso tambien tiene que haber un elemento para eliminarlo de la lista (en este caso un a(anchor) con el texto "X" (está escrito el código de eso último pero como no se crean la tabla no se si esta bien).

La consola me tira el siguiente error cuando clikeo para agregar:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
        at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>
```

(aunque segun yo no tiene nada que ver este error para con lo que estoy pidiendo ayuda)

Tambien quisiera saber si lo demas como el contador de productos y el contador de total están bien.

Tambien quisiera saber como puedo hacer con css para que los divs creados se pongan uno al lado del otro.

El html

```
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Productos</h1>
            <div id="productos">
            </div>
            <h2>Carrito</h2>
            <div id="carrito">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>seleccionados</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <p>numero de productos:</p>
            <p id="cantidad"></p>
            <p>precio total:</p>
            <p id="total"></p>
            <button id="Caro">producto mas caro</button>
            <p id="preciomascaro"></p>
        </main>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

el javascript

```
     //variables 
    var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var total = 0;
    var contador = 0;
    peticion.open("GET", "./productos.json", true);
    
    //peticion de los productos y creacion de los div
    
    peticion.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var productos = JSON.parse(peticion.responseText);
    
            productos.forEach(productos => {
    
                var folletos = document.getElementById("productos");
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                folletos.appendChild(div);
    
                var vnombre = document.createElement("p");
                vnombre.innerText = productos.nombre
                div.appendChild(vnombre)
    
                var imagen = document.createElement('img');
                imagen.setAttribute("alt", "imagen del producto");
                imagen.setAttribute("src", productos.url_foto);
                div.appendChild(imagen);
    
                var descripcion = document.createElement("p");
                descripcion.innerText = productos.descripcion;
                div.appendChild(descripcion);
    
                var precio = document.createElement("p");
                precio.innerText = productos.precio;
                div.appendChild(precio);
    
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', '#');
                link.text = ("Agregar al carrito")
                div.appendChild(link);
    
                //crear fila de la tabla
                link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
    
                    var fila = document.createElement("tr");
                    var celdanombre = document.createElement("td");
                    celdanombre = productos.nombre;
                    fila.appendChild(celdanombre);
    
                    var celdaprecio = document.createElement("td");
                    celdaprecio = productos.precio;
                    fila.appendChild(celdaprecio);
    
                    //agregar elemento sumar en total y contador
                    var ptotal = document.getElementById("total");
                    total = total + productos.precio;
                    ptotal.innerText = total;
    
                    var pcontador = document.getElementById("cantidad")
                    contador = contador + 1
                    pcontador.innerText = contador
                    
                    //borrar de la fila
                    var celdaborrar = document.createElement("td");
                    var borrar = document.createElement("a");
                    borrar.setAttribute("href", "#");
                    borrar.innerText("X");
                    celdaborrar.appendChild(borrar);
                    fila.appendChild(celdaborrar);
    
                    //borrar elemento restar en total y contador
                    borrar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove());
                        Total = total - productos.precio;
                        contador = contador - 1
    
                    });
    
                    document.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(fila);
                });
    
            });
        };
    });
    peticion.send();
    var precioMasAlto = -1;
    var BotonMasCaro = document.getElementById("Caro");
    
    BotonMasCaro.addEventListener("clik", function (event) {
        var productosCarrito = document.querySelector('tbody').children;
        
        for (let index = 0; index < productosCarrito.length; index++) {
            const productorow = productosCarrito[index];
            
            let productoNombre = productoRow.children[0].innerText;
            let productoPrecio = Number(productoRow.children[1].innerText);
            
            if (productoPrecio>precioMasAlto) {
    
                precioMasAlto = productoPrecio
                
            }
            var preciomascaro = document.getElementById("preciomascaro")
            preciomascaro.innerText = precioMasAlto
    
        }
        
    
    });
```

el json

```
    [
    {
        "nombre": "Aire Acondicinado",
        "url_foto": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_760023-MLA40007585180_122019-P.webp",
        "descripcion": "Aire Acondicinado Frio/Calor",
        "precio": 50000
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Bicicleta",
        "url_foto": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_966646-MLA52248035361_112022-P.webp",
        "descripcion": "Mountain Bike R29",
        "precio": 100000
    },
    {
        "nombre": "TV",
        "url_foto": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_686221-MLA51543966938_092022-P.webp",
        "descripcion": "TV 55 UHD 4K",
        "precio": 73000
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Telefono",
        "url_foto": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_890555-MLA50912449037_072022-P.webp",
        "descripcion": "Telefono - Samsung",
        "precio": 65000
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Licuadora",
        "url_foto": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_791854-MLA45158798057_032021-P.webp",
        "descripcion": "Licuadora - Liliana",
        "precio": 23000
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Monitor",
        "url_foto": "https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_796587-MLA46165231779_052021-P.webp",
        "descripcion": "Monitor - Samsung LED - 20",
        "precio": 83000
    }
]
```

Comment: A ver, estás pidiendo muchas cosas, y así no funciona este sitio. Por lo que veo debes haber heredado ese código porque los fallos que tienes son demasiado básicos para que los estes preguntando aquí, y teniendo en cuenta que gran parte de ese código está bien

Comment: Es decir, son fallos de sintaxis en varias lineas, que deben ser nuevas, porque en el resto de tu código hay las mismas funciones y propiedades, y estan bien escritas... así que repasa bien todo lo que aparece debajo de `link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {` pues es allí donde se concentran los errores, algunos de concepto pues machacas variables recien creadas con valores a pelo destrozando los objetos que creas

Comment: ¿pero donde esta el error? si pregunto es porque no lo veo, y me imagine que pido muchas cosas pero es que no me dejaba publicar la pregunta solo con el primer pedido porque era mucho codigo, y recien empiezo con la programacion por eso las preguntas basicas, el codigo lo escribi todo yo excepto el for

Comment: Ya te lo he dicho, tienes unos cuantos debajo de esta línea `link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {`.  Fíjate bien en cada línea debajo de esa y comparalas entre si con los otros grupos, pues en algunos lo has hecho bien y en otros no.  Si el código lo has hecho tu deberías ser capaz de verlo.  Te indico uno para que vayas pensando porque esta mal: `celdanombre = productos.nombre;`  (y fíjate que haces justo la línea anterior)

Comment: ya veo porque descreíste que escribiera el codigo me faltaba el innertext para pedir el nombre y el precio y en el de borrar me comi un = para hacer que escribiera una "X"

Comment: el contador de productos y sumador de precios funcionan bien, pero no se restan cuando elimino

Comment: Bravo :-)  En [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/rhvbpmzL/1/) te dejo tu código con todo funcionando bien... revísalo y aplica los cambios que te falten.. saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda amigo :) saludos!